# SoundPool: звуки перестали проигрываться при переходе с WAV на OGG?

Tags: java, android, wav, ogg

Кто знает особенности класса "SoundPool" помогите разобраться.
Раньше использовал звуки в формате WAV и они проигрывались без проблем.
После замены звуков на формат OGG (см. снимок экрана) звуки перестали проигрываться (сейчас status = -1, до изменений на формате WAV был status = 0).
[image]
Делал: Build -> **Rebuild Project**, перезагружал компьютер не помогает.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, объясните как поправить?

[Исходник проекта](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X-Ju1lGmP0MJvlkMWR_ajWg5UD-SUlHB)

Comment: Работайте через [AssetFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor).  `soundPool.play(soundPool.load(getAssets().openFd("myMusic.ogg"), 0), 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);`.

Comment: Попробуйте, для теста, воспроизвести этот же файл через класс `MediaPlayer`  - возможно версия кодека не поддерживается устройством. Если воспроизведётся, то может быть файлы слишком большие - `SoundPool` рассчитан на воспроизведение коротких звуков (хотя обычно он просто не играет их до конца, если файл больше чем надо).

Comment: Выскакивает ошибка: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: nine.ogg    если делать через sp.play(sp.load(getAssets().openFd(arrSoundId[id]), 0),1, 1, 0, 0, 1);